# Android - HTML Parsing vs JavaScript - What is the efficient approach?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, parsing

I am grabbing data from a site's page (which is generated and that I have no control over) The part of the page that I care about most is the in the head like as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
Item.id       = '11457';
Item.comments = [{"score":9,"comment_id":291622,"comment":"For RDM this offers the most haste for the feet, beating the haste+3 from dusk+1.","date_posted":"2011-09-22 08:37:19","char_id":724996,"deleted":0,"type":"item","user_char_id":91314,"avatar":"724996_N9Bdg4hpuP.jpg","user_id":54878,"char_name":"Moogleking","server_name":"Shiva","rating":null,"ident_id":96474,"reports":null,"dismiss":null}, ...]
```

And other misc. information ID'd by their span ID.

I'm just wondering what is the correct/efficient approach to gathering the data in Android programming? Is is parsing the html in DOM? Is it sticking to a WebView/JavaScript Interface?

Comment: are you trying to Scrape some HTML page from android app?

Comment: why dont you simply match using regex?

Answer (score 0):

http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/

It parses everything that has an xml form(HTML,XML,XSLT), is open source, is fast and very lightweight. It might not have documentation but the support over the web is in very detail.

WebView from my experience loads very slowly so I would not advise something like that.

Comment: I will definately take a look. A friend off mine also suggested [this project](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) as a resource.

Comment: this is more efficient for HTML approach as it has special methods for "get" and "post" and it is doing in an async thread. On the other hand htmlcleaner has support for get and post calls but it works like a charm basic on every XML type file, including HTML. It also supports the very useful XPath syntax.